# Counting sundays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this little riddle that I wanna solve it is bugging me this is the riddle:

1 Jan 1900 was a Monday. Thirty days has September, April, June and November. All the rest have thirty-one, Saving February alone, Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine. And on leap years, twenty-nine. A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400. How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

**THE CODE I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

```
var sundays = 0;
  for (var year = 1901; year <= 2000; year++) {
    for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {

   }
}
```

**WHAT I NEED:**

I am not sure what the if statment would be to solve this?

Thanks and please help me.

Comment: I would say it's also required to know what day of the week Jan 1 1901 was (after Googling I believe it was a Tuesday)

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809723/counting-sundays-in-javascript.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to make a `Date` object, then see if it's a Sunday:

```
new Date(year, month, 1).getDay() == 0 // Sunday is 0
```

However, JavaScript months are 0-11, not 1-12, so you need to fix your loop (or use `month - 1` in the `Date` constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Your code so far is fine, but now for each month you need to check what day the first of the month was. You can use `Date` objects to achieve this.

```
var sundays = 0;

for (var year = 1901; year<2001; year++) {
    for (var month = 1; month<=12; month++) {
        if (new Date(year, month-1, 1).getDay() == 0) {
            sundays++;
        }
    }
}
```

As @Amadan pointed out, getDay returns 0 for Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one Date object and increment the year and month:

```
var from=new Date(), 
m= 0, 
y= 1901, 
A= [];
while(y<2001){
    if(m== 11){
        m= 0;
        ++y;
    }
    from.setFullYear(y,m++,1);
    if(from.getDay()=== 0) A.push(from.toLocaleDateString());
}
A.length+' Sundays begin months between 1901 and 2000.\n'+
A.join('; ');
```

/*  returned value:

156 Sundays begin months between 1901 and 2000.

9/1/1901; 6/1/1902; 2/1/1903; 3/1/1903; 11/1/1903; 5/1/1904; 1/1/1905; 10/1/1905; 4/1/1906; 7/1/1906; 9/1/1907; 3/1/1908; 11/1/1908; 8/1/1909; 5/1/1910; 1/1/1911; 10/1/1911; 9/1/1912; 6/1/1913; 2/1/1914; 3/1/1914; 11/1/1914; 8/1/1915; 10/1/1916; 4/1/1917; 7/1/1917; 9/1/1918; 6/1/1919; 2/1/1920; 8/1/1920; 5/1/1921; 1/1/1922; 10/1/1922; 4/1/1923; 7/1/1923; 6/1/1924; 2/1/1925; 3/1/1925; 11/1/1925; 8/1/1926; 5/1/1927; 1/1/1928; 4/1/1928; 7/1/1928; 9/1/1929; 6/1/1930; 2/1/1931; 3/1/1931; 11/1/1931; 5/1/1932; 1/1/1933; 10/1/1933; 4/1/1934; 7/1/1934; 9/1/1935; 3/1/1936; 11/1/1936; 8/1/1937; 5/1/1938; 1/1/1939; 10/1/1939; 9/1/1940; 6/1/1941; 2/1/1942; 3/2/1942; 11/2/1942; 8/1/1943; 10/1/1944; 4/1/1945; 7/1/1945; 9/1/1946; 6/1/1947; 2/1/1948; 8/1/1948; 5/1/1949; 1/1/1950; 10/1/1950; 4/1/1951; 7/1/1951; 6/1/1952; 2/1/1953; 3/1/1953; 11/1/1953; 8/1/1954; 5/1/1955; 1/1/1956; 4/1/1956; 7/1/1956; 9/1/1957; 6/1/1958; 2/1/1959; 3/1/1959; 11/1/1959; 5/1/1960; 1/1/1961; 10/1/1961; 4/1/1962; 7/1/1962; 9/1/1963; 3/1/1964; 11/1/1964; 8/1/1965; 5/1/1966; 1/1/1967; 10/1/1967; 9/1/1968; 6/1/1969; 2/1/1970; 3/1/1970; 11/1/1970; 8/1/1971; 10/1/1972; 4/1/1973; 7/1/1973; 9/1/1974; 6/1/1975; 2/1/1976; 8/1/1976; 5/1/1977; 1/1/1978; 10/1/1978; 4/1/1979; 7/1/1979; 6/1/1980; 2/1/1981; 3/1/1981; 11/1/1981; 8/1/1982; 5/1/1983; 1/1/1984; 4/1/1984; 7/1/1984; 9/1/1985; 6/1/1986; 2/1/1987; 3/1/1987; 11/1/1987; 5/1/1988; 1/1/1989; 10/1/1989; 4/1/1990; 7/1/1990; 9/1/1991; 3/1/1992; 11/1/1992; 8/1/1993; 5/1/1994; 1/1/1995; 10/1/1995; 9/1/1996; 6/1/1997; 2/1/1998; 3/1/1998; 11/1/1998; 8/1/1999; 10/1/2000

*/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a longer way but it works.

```js
function countingSundays(firstYear, lastYear) {
  let days = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday',
  ];
  const startDaysMonths = [
    1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335,
  ];
  const startDaysMonthsLeap = [
    1, 32, 61, 92, 122, 153, 183, 214, 245, 275, 306, 336,
  ];

  let firstDayOfYear = (year) => {
    let yearDays = {};
    let index = 0;
    let last = 0;

    for (let i = 1900; i < 2000; i++) {
      index = last % 7;
      Object.assign(yearDays, { [i]: days[index] });
      if (i % 4 === 0 && i !== 1900) {
        last = last + 2;
      } else {
        last++;
      }
    }
    return yearDays[year];
  };

  const NumberOfSundayInYear = (year) => {
    const leapYear = year % 4 === 0 ? true : false;
    const totalDays = leapYear ? 366 : 365;
    const firstDay = days.indexOf(firstDayOfYear(year));
    let index = 0;
    let current = firstDay;
    let SundayNumber = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < totalDays + 1; i++) {
      index = current % 7;
      if (days[index] === 'Sunday') {
        if (!leapYear && startDaysMonths.includes(i + 1)) {
          SundayNumber++;
        }
        if (leapYear && startDaysMonthsLeap.includes(i + 1)) {
          SundayNumber++;
        }
      }
      current++;
    }
    return SundayNumber;
  };

  let countingSundayArray = [];

  for (let index = firstYear; index < lastYear + 1; index++) {
    if (index === 2000) {
      countingSundayArray.push(NumberOfSundayInYear(index) - 1);
    } else {
      countingSundayArray.push(NumberOfSundayInYear(index));
    }
  }


  return countingSundayArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

console.log(countingSundays(1995, 2000));
```